# Pixel-by-pixel creation of a black-and-white image based on an existing data array storing a value from 0 to 255

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I am trying to encrypt/decrypt a b/w image based on the SP network algorithm. The problem is the following: after getting the values of each pixel and "encrypting" them, I can't create a new b/w image already. I tried using .setRGB(), but later realized that it was a bit more complicated than I imagined. I think we need to use the WritebleRaster class to do this more correctly, but firstly I don't understand how, and secondly, I'm not sure if this is the right approach.

```
    public BufferedImage[] mainFunction(){
        WritableRaster wr = originalImage.getRaster();
        BufferedImage encodeDecodeImages[] = new BufferedImage[2];
        encodeDecodeImages[0] = new BufferedImage(originalImage.getWidth(), originalImage.getHeight(), originalImage.getType());
        encodeDecodeImages[1] = new BufferedImage(originalImage.getWidth(), originalImage.getHeight(), originalImage.getType());
        initSequences();
        // test();
        int size;
        int ch;
        int first = 0;
        int second = 0;
        //test();

        if (originalImage != null)
        {
            size = originalImage.getWidth();
            for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
                for (int j = 0; j < size; j += 2)
                {
                    first = this.pixelMatrix[i][j];
                    second = this.pixelMatrix[i][j + 1];
                    ch = (first << 8) + second;
                    for (int r = 0; r < rounds * 4; r += 4)
                    {
                        first = (ch & 0x0000FF00) >> 8;
                        first = split(first, r);
                        second = ch & 0x000000FF;
                        second = split(second, r + 2);
                        ch = (first << 8) + second;
                        ch = permute(ch, r / 4);
                    }
                    first = (ch & 0x0000FF00) >> 8;
                    second = ch & 0x000000FF;
                    this.pixelMatrixEncode[i][j] = first;
                    this.pixelMatrixEncode[i][j + 1] = second;
                    wr.setSample(i, j, 0, first);   
                    encodeDecodeImages[0].setRGB(i, j, first);
                    wr.setSample(i, j + 1, 0, second);
                    encodeDecodeImages[0].setRGB(i, j + 1, second);
                    int w = 0;
                }
                ColorModel cm = ColorModel.getRGBdefault();
                BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(cm, wr, cm.isAlphaPremultiplied(), null);
                //encodeDecodeImages[0] = image;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < size; j += 2){
                    first = this.pixelMatrixEncode[i][j];
                    second = this.pixelMatrixEncode[i][j + 1];

                for (int r = (rounds * 4) - 1; r >= 0; r -= 4)
                {
                    ch = (int)((first << 8) + second);
                    ch = permuteDecode(ch, r / 4);
                    first = (int)((ch & 0xff00) >> 8);
                    first = splitDecode(first, r - 3);
                    second = (int)(ch & 0x00ff);
                    second = splitDecode(second, r - 1);
                }
                this.pixelMatrixDecode[i][j] = first;
                this.pixelMatrixDecode[i][j + 1] = second;
                wr.setSample(i, j, 0, (int)first);
                encodeDecodeImages[1].setRGB(i, j, first);
                wr.setSample(i, j + 1, 0, (int)second);
                encodeDecodeImages[1].setRGB(i, j + 1, second);
                int w = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        return encodeDecodeImages;
    }
```

Actually, when I tried to build an image via setRGB(), the image was not built at all and I don't understand why

```
try {
            BufferedImage[] encodeDecodeImgs = model.mainFunction();
            ImageIO.write(encodeDecodeImgs[0], "bmp", new File("C:\\Users\\pbiar\\Desktop\\uchVsyakoe\\PASZI_JrOkata\\L3\\Source\\Encode.bmp"));
            ImageIO.write(encodeDecodeImgs[1], "bmp", new File("C:\\Users\\pbiar\\Desktop\\uchVsyakoe\\PASZI_JrOkata\\L3\\Source\\Decode.bmp"));
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
            }
```

Comment: You can try to use `BufferedImage.getRaster()` and / or `BufferedImage.getWritableRaster()` to get and set pixels on your images. For the writing to a file you should try to output the result of `ImageIO.getWriterFormatNames()` to find out if the desired format is supported for writing.